# Getting multiple out when using NOT EQUAL operator

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

[image: DEPARTMENT TABLE]

[image: DEPENDENT TABLE]

How to display name of the department managers (fname, lname) who have no dependent?

Tried this:

```
Select DISTINCT EMPLOYEE.Fname,EMPLOYEE.Lname 
from EMPLOYEE 
INNER JOIN DEPENDENT ON (EMPLOYEE.Ssn != DEPENDENT.Essn);
```

Comment: Could you please provide DDL (CREATE TABLE Dependent\G...) and DML (INSERT INTO Dependent VALUS(...)) - help us to help you :-)

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, I did the following:

I created two tables, Employee and Dependent - note that I only created the important fields - name and SSN - you can add the details for yourself.

```
CREATE TABLE `Employee` 
(
  `LName` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SSN` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `Dependent` (
  `Name` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Essn` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `Employee` VALUES ('Smith','12345-6789'),('Wong','33344-5555'),('Zelaya','99988-7777'),('Wallace','98765-4321'),('Mr-X','22222-3333');  -- For NULL values of Essn, see below.
```

and

```
INSERT INTO `Dependent` VALUES ('Alice','33344-5555'),('Theodore','33344-5555'),('Joy','33344-5555'),('Abner','98765-4321'),('Michael','12345-6789'),('Alice','12345-6789'),('Elizabeth','12345-6789');
```

You can see that Mr-X and Zelaya (employees) have no Essn in the Dependent tables - i.e. they have no dependents. Now for the SQL:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Employee e 
WHERE e.SSN 
NOT IN 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT(Essn) 
  FROM Dependent
);
```

Only works if the tables join on a `NOT NULL` field.

```
+--------+------------+
| LName  |       SSN  |
+--------+------------+
| Zelaya | 99988-7777 |
| Mr-X   | 22222-3333 |
+--------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql>
```

For NULL SSN in the Employee table, use the following query, (as pointed out by @Paul White). I also added this line to test:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES('EBorg', NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

SELECT * FROM Employee emp
WHERE emp.LName NOT IN
(
  SELECT DISTINCT(e.LName)  
  FROM Employee e  
  JOIN Dependent d 
  ON e.SSN = d.Essn
);
```

Result:

```
+--------+------------+
| LName  |       SSN  |
+--------+------------+
| Zelaya | 99988-7777 |
| Mr-X   | 22222-3333 |
| EBorg  | NULL       |
+--------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Initially, I assumed that everyone would have an SSN, however if they
don't, then the second query will work - I'm assuming no NULL LNames :-). It's very bad practice not to have a `PRIMARY KEY` which would mean that the simpler query would word.

Or, for `NULL`s, you could just a add a `UNION` of my first query and `SSN IS NULL` thus

```
SELECT * FROM Employee e 
WHERE e.SSN 
NOT IN 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT(Essn) 
  FROM Dependent
)
UNION
SELECT * FROM Employee e
WHERE e.SSN IS NULL;  -- same result as above.
```

Following more discussion with @PaulWhite, there are two more queries which will work providing the (correct 3 line) result shown above.

```
SELECT e.*
FROM Employee e
WHERE NOT Exists
(SELECT 1
 FROM Dependent d
 WHERE e.SSN = d.Essn
);
```

And (the best one!)

```
SELECT  e.*
FROM Employee e
LEFT JOIN
Dependent d
ON      e.SSN = d.Essn
WHERE   d.Essn IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select EMPLOYEE.Fname, EMPLOYEE.Lname 
from EMPLOYEE 
LEFT JOIN DEPENDENT ON EMPLOYEE.Ssn = DEPENDENT.Essn
where DEPENDENT.Essn is null;
```

inner join on != would find matches on multiple rows  as long as DEPENDENT has two unique rows then would find at least one match on !=

you need to look for the match and then find (where) those with no match

not exists may be a bit more efficient but you probably don't have enough data that it makes a difference

```
Select e.Fname, e.Lname 
from EMPLOYEE e 
where not exists (select 1 from DEPENDENT where DEPENDENT.Essn = e.Ssn);
```